# OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback interface shows error with google play services appcompatv7

Tags: android

helo pals,am trying to add android street view panorama to my app.When i use "public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback",it displays this error message "OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback cannot be resolved to a type".Please how do i resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.grade and see if you're on the latest version of play-services and appcompat-v7

Updating to these versions worked for me:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'`